# Freshly created ionic3 app not working on android device

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a new Ionic 3 app, i haven't touched it yet, it works fine on browser however when i tried to build and run it on a actual android device, the generated apk output is always

> "Couldn't connect to the server. (http://localhost:8080/)"

see: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22809323/43546424-0974fb28-95f2-11e8-92be-1d4099039f85.png

Here's the process i've made

`-ionic start apktest blank
 -cd apktest
 -ionic cordova platform add android
 -ionic cordova build android
 -ionic cordova run android`

PS: I already have those android sdk and java

Can anybody enlighten me about this issue? Thanks

Comment: Additional: What i have found is that, the app actually works however when i tested it out on android version 4.4.2 kitkat. it shows the above issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error message because your app probably uses a plugin that does not support Android 4.x.

Run `ionic cordova plugins` to check if it contains an entry for the plugin `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` with version `2.x`.

If it exists, you can downgrade it plugin to the last version that supported Android 4.x:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
```

Some background information: This plugin used to apply only to iOS, where it replaced the UIWebView with WKWebView, but on July 23rd 2018 they released version 2.0 of the plugin, that also included changes to the webview used on Android. The Android webview now uses a local webserver at `localhost:8080` to show your app instead of requesting the files directly from the file system.

More elaborate information and alternative solutions:
https://ionic.zone/debug/ionic-and-android-4

Comment: Thank you @janpio, this answers my question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before.

I modify the file config.xml adding the following inside the platform tag.

```
  <preference name=“loadUrlTimeoutValue” value=“700000” />
```

Comment: i have tried this one, however it still does not work on my end :(